# ORDER one row normally, but second row on other value of a third JOIN row

Tags: mysql, sql

In these tables

```
[   id    -   title   -   meta ]
[    1    -     A     -    A1  ]
[    2    -     A     -    A2  ]
[    3    -     A     -    A3  ]
[    4    -     C     -    A1  ]
[    5    -     C     -    A3  ]
[    6    -     B     -    B1  ]
[    7    -     B     -    B2  ]

[    id     -    rating  -     title     -   meta  ]
[    1      -       9    -       A       -    A1   ]
[    2      -       5    -       C       -    A1   ]
[    3      -       4    -       A       -    A2   ]
[    4      -       6    -       A       -    A3   ]
[    5      -       8    -       B       -    B1   ]
[    6      -       18   -       C       -    A3   ]
[    7      -       12   -       B       -    B2   ]
```

And right now my query is

```
"SELECT DISTINCT a.title, a.meta, SUM(ra.vote) as rating
FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.meta = b.meta AND a.title = b.title
WHERE a.title = :title
ORDER BY a.title, rating DESC"
```

in my PHP codes, I `echo` the column `title` value `DISTINCT` then i put all the values of the `meta`s where its `title` is duplicated under it.

Now my problem is that i want to `ORDER` the `meta`s values depending on its `rating`

What i get is a random order, But i want it to be like this

```
                A
      A1(9) -> A3(6) -> A2(4)

                B
         B2(12) -> B1(8)

                C
         A3(18) -> A1(5)
```

So when i get the `meta`s values, it comes ordered by the `rating`

something like this

```
[   id    -   title   -   meta    -    rating ]
[    1    -     A     -    A1     -       9   ]
[    3    -     A     -    A3     -       6   ]
[    3    -     A     -    A2     -       4   ]
[    5    -     B     -    B2     -       12  ]
[    6    -     C     -    A3     -       18  ]
[    2    -     C     -    A1     -       5   ]
```

Comment: I don't understand your diagram of what you want it to look like.  Can you post what you want it to look like as a table result?

Comment: @justiceorjustus just added an example table of the result i want.

Answer (score 0):

> What i get is a random order

What you get is not random order but random data.

The query:

```
SELECT a.title, a.meta
...
GROUP BY a.meta
```

is invalid SQL. For queries that contain the `GROUP BY` clause, the `SELECT` clause is allowed to contain only these kinds of expressions:

- expressions that also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause;
- [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html);
- expressions that are functionally dependent on expressions that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

The expression `a.title` from the `SELECT` clause doesn't fit in any of the above categories.

Prior to version 5.7.5, MySQL accepts such queries but, as the [documentation explains](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

> ... a MySQL extension to the standard `SQL` use of `GROUP BY` permits the select list, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on `GROUP BY` columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an `ORDER BY` clause.

#### What that means in plain English?

Take a look at the first two rows from the second table:

```
[    id     -    rating  -     title     -   meta  ]
[    1      -       9    -       A       -    A1   ]
[    2      -       5    -       C       -    A1   ]
```

and the relevant part of the query again:

```
SELECT a.title, a.meta
...
GROUP BY a.meta
```

MySQL creates a single group from these two rows (because of `GROUP BY a.meta`). From one group it **generates** a row in the result set, using the expressions provided in the `SELECT` clause.

What value should it choose for `a.title`? As explained above, it picks one of them without any rule.

It can pick `A` now but if you run the query after the data in the table changes it can pick `C`, Also, it can pick `C` if you export the table and import it into a different server (or on the same server after you remove the original table).

Comment: So there is no possible way to do it using my query? or there is a way to use a condition to solve the problem? Because i guess in this case i should use `GROUP BY a.title` but need to put a condition for it to order the `meta`s, is that possible?

Comment: i updated the query and removed the group by part, since it is useless and added DISTINCT